# Помогите понять код

Tags: java

имеем код

```
public class Test {
    static int var3 = 1;

    public static void test(int var3) {
        var3 += 3;
    }

    public static void test2() {
        var3 += 3;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test(Test.var3);
        System.out.println(var3);

         test2();
        System.out.println(var3);
    }
}
```

вывод : 1  4

как так получается, что передав в метод `test` поле класса `Test.var3` , она не меняеться.
но, если изменить сигнатуру метода `public static void test(int var3)`
на `public static void test(int a)` то меняеться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При записи `(int var3)` внутри метода создаётся локальная переменная с именем `var3` которая никак не является ссылкой на свойство класса. В себе она содержит копию значения, переданного в метод. Поэтому в теле метода вы уже оперируете именно этой внутренней переменной.

При записи `(int a)`  метод уже работает с переменной самого класса.

Именно поэтому часто в конструкторах, чтобы отличить аргументы, переданные внутрь и свойства самого класса пишут так:

```
....(int param1, int param2) {
    this.param1 = param1;
    this.param2 = param2;
}
```

Чтобы чётко компилятору дать знать что есть свойство класса, а что переменная метода. Иначе он просто не знает что из них что и работает с аргументом в локальном скоупе.